# Wordpress plugin keeps firing register_post_type() on init even when idle

Tags: wordpress

**Background:**

I am writing a plugin using boilerplate code from the [Wordpress Plugin Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) and wondering why a particular function keeps firing on it's own. I have also added the `add_action()` function at the bottom and hooked it to `init`, which I am guessing is the cause of the post-type to be registered over and over.

**An Observation and my attempt to 'fix' it:**

Watching the log, I noticed that this function keeps firing on its own but I cannot figure out why.  After some reading, I tried to add the if-statement at the top of my function, checking for `DOING_AJAX`, which seems to suppress the post-type to be registering over and over.

**Question:** Why does Wordpress exhibit this behavior?

**Question:** Is it safe to take out the if-statement at the top of the function and let Wordpress keep 'registering' the post-type?

---

**The function looks like this:**

```
function pluginprefix_setup_post_type() {

  // Exit function if doing an AJAX request
  if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
    return;
  }

  // set up labels
  $labels = array(
    'name'  => 'Products',
    'singular_name' => 'Product',
    'add_new' => 'Add Product',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add Product',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Product',
    'new_item' => 'New Product',
    'all_items' => 'All Products',
    'view_item' => 'View Product',
    'search_items' => 'Search Products',
    'not_found' =>  'No Product Found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Product found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Products',
  );

  //register post type
  error_log('Registering custom post type: my_product');

  register_post_type( 'my_product', array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category' ),
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'myproduct' ),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'pluginprefix_setup_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 2):

***Yes***, you can leave the post type registration how it is. The `init` hook is fired at a certain point during the loading of the WordPress system every time the page is requested. The post type is included in the `$wp_post_types` global variable at runtime which allows it to be used on the site. So in this scenario, you will have your post type log that it's always being registered. That's normal.

To answer your questions a bit more directly:

> Why does Wordpress exhibit this behaviour?

It stores post types in a global available at runtime. It's just how WordPress does it.

> Is it safe to take out the if-statement at the top of the function and let Wordpress keep 'registering' the post-type?

Completely safe and intended.

Comment: Sweeeeeeeeeeeet.  Thanks, Daniel James!